# .NET send Ctrl-V to active app

Tags: .net

I try to create a program that catch hotkey to copy a pre-defined text to clipboard and paste it to active application (ei, text editor, address box, user input fields, etc.)

Based on the discussion at [link1](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886756/trigger-os-to-copy-ctrlc-or-ctrl-x-programmatically) I can create the program I want. From my testing, it works with notepad, windows explorer addressbar, user input fields from web browsers. However, it does not work with MS office application (Word, Excel, Outlook, etc) and web browser address bar (chrome, IE). It does copy the text in to clipboard, but can not paste the text to applications. If I press my hotkey and then Ctrl-V, I got the text pasted but it's not what I want.

I am wondering whether it's possible to make it work with MS office apps or not. So far, I haven't found any good suggestion from the web.

Can any body give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: In an ms office app or the browser, you might need to set focus on the UI element where you want to do the Ctrl V

Comment: Thanks. It works with UI control on web browser, but not address bar. MS Office, I haven't found any luck.