# how to get selected text any application to VB.NET With out press Clrt + C

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, vbscript

When the user selects a text anywhere in any application,I want to capture the selected text.
i wont to capture automatically the selected text.with out using Clrt + C.

can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use global windows hooks such as WH_MOUSE_LL to capture the mouse events.

A possible solution would be to capture the mouse up event, WM_LBUTTONUP, through the global windows hooks and then trigger a copy to the clipboard (such as programatically sending a ctrl+c)

This link gives an example of hooking into global windows events.  This specific one is for keyboard events however it should be similar for mouse events.

[Using global keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL) in WPF / C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639331/using-global-keyboard-hook-wh-keyboard-ll-in-wpf-c-sharp)

This link contains suggestions for triggering os level copies to the clipboard.

[Trigger OS to copy (ctrl+c or Ctrl-x) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886756/trigger-os-to-copy-ctrlc-or-ctrl-x-programmatically)

This is neither an elegant solution or a complete solution as it will try to copy after every mouse click regardless of whether text is highlighted, but hopefully can be used as a starting point.