# Is there a way to programmatically press keyboard keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Client requires to programmatically press Keyboard keys like "C", "Ctrl", "Shift", "5", etc.

I have checked some APIs but only handing of key presses are available.
Example :

```
.keypress()
```

Are there available functions which can mimic this behavior?

[Updated Code]

```
$("#input").focus();
window.crossBrowser_initKeyboardEvent("keypress", {"key": 1, "char": "!", shiftKey: true});
```

My goal in the updated code is to focus a textfield and trigger keypresss such that the character I want to show is shown ion the textfield. But, the above code is not working also.

Comment: If you could find out why, and in what context this is required, we might be able to help . . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Comment: @PatDobson: What the client wants is to be able to copy item to clipboard in Chrome by just clicking a button without using flash (just pure JS). I have checked through this but it seems not supported due to some security risks. So, client thinks that if there's a way to trigger the keyboard such that CTRL+C is pressed programmatically then it might solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 8; // # Some key code value
    $("input").trigger(e);
```

More [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events), Also See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886756/trigger-os-to-copy-ctrlc-or-ctrl-x-programmatically)

Comment: Does this trigger the system key such that it seems the user has clicked CTRL+C? Please refer to [Updated Code] above.

Comment: @KimHonoridez go through the second link i have provided

Comment: Getting, "TypeError: inst is undefined" on trigger call.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use jQuery, this is what I recommend, paste this right into your script tags, run it, and press capital A to see a message.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) 
{                                            //Start of addEventListener
       if (e.which == 65)                    //When A is pressed
                alert("A was pressed");      //Message will show
}, false);                                   //End of addEventListener
```

Comment: The question is about firing the keydown event and not handling it, this doesn't answer the question.